# Automatically assist when linking to a Stack Exchange Question

Tags: feature-request

When you place a link to a stackexchange question on a post, wouldn't it be easy to identify the post name, and place a nice bit of feedback on the link.  You could automatically flesh out the link text as well.

What I mean is:

- Click the "Add link" button.
- Copy/Paste your link into the text box
- Stack Exchange identifies that this is a question on a stack exchange website.
- Stack Exchange then places the question title automatically into the link "text" section.
- Possibly even displays a hover in the main page with details of the question when hovering on the link.

Comment: Sort of similar to when you post it in Chat?

Comment: How often do you need to link to SE posts from SE posts? When I see intra-SE links, they're usually duplicate links posted either out of confusion about how the site works or the desire for easy rep.

Comment: This already happens on intra-site links, those to metas and a few other cases are already changed into links with the titles...you just need to post the URL by itself and it happens automagically.

Comment: I just tried then.  It leaves "enter link description here" and the link itself does nothing special...

Comment: ahhh. That behaviour should be wired for the people who click the button too then. But yes you are right, if you straight copy paste the link without using the HTML link button. My original question still stands.

Comment: @Spence You've just discovered that the functionality already exists and that you need fewer clicks to achieve the same effect. Why then, would you insist that it be implemented for something more complex?

Comment: I'm all for shortcuts, but it's not obvious to the user.  If I want to post a link to something else it doesn't work unless I used the post link workflow.  To me a shortcut should always be possible from the full API as well.